# Invisible spot on a colorful graph, what am I?

Tags: riddle

Invisible spot on a colorful graph,
less than a hundred and more than a half,
a proof that beginning of earth and titan exists,
"A" is the starting letter on all my guests' list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is:

> Area 51

Invisible spot on a colorful graph,

> The location of Area 51 on the US map was secret for a long time.

less than a hundred and more than a half,

> Fifty one fits this.

a proof that beginning of earth and titan exists,

> according to pop culture (maybe now debunked), Area 51 houses Extra Terrestrials (E.T.)

"A" is the starting letter on all my guests' list.

> A is for Alien.

Comment: How does it fit the third line?

Comment: Proof that E.T. exists?

Comment: oh, I see, gotcha!

Comment: Nice and fast!  Either you're too smart or I gave away too much =D

Comment: 2nd and 3rd lines give away much. First number less than hundred and greater than half of it...

Comment: @Aravind I thought he meant less than 100 and more than 0.5.

Comment: @pacoverflow it was intended to be misleading, but didn't work on Aravind I guess

Comment: I don't understand how this fits the riddle (other than line 2 obv). Please can you edit in an explanation?

Comment: @randal'thor line 1: colorful graph is the worldmap, and Area51 is not shown on the map (as a hidden base).  Line 3: Beginning of "E"arth and "T"itan exists - E.T. - Extra Terrestrials aka aliens.

Comment: Thanks for editing! Now I can upvote question and answer ;-) I was expecting there to be a reference to [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) in there somewhere...